# Possible to find a list of followers or following on Tumblr using API or other means?

Tags: api, tumblr

The [Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/api) supports basic content reading, but I have not yet found a way to get either the list of followers, or the list of people you are following. The API seems to only return the follower count. The [theme documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/custom_themes) has a block that can show who you follow, which is the closest I have found to what I want.

My question is: Given a user's email address and password, is it possible to find either of these lists, through any means? Some sort of background job might be necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question:

While this was not possible with the Tumblr API before, the newly release [API v2](http://engineering.tumblr.com/post/7541361718/introducing-tumblrs-new-api) now supports both types of information.

[`/followers`](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-followers) and [`/user/following`](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#m-ug-following) are the relevant commands. They return JSON objects which list the blogs that follow a user, or that a user follows. It looks like they also require OAUTH to access, as this is not public information.

Answer (score 5):

I am looking for the same thing and one idea I came up with is for the specific Tumblr user to create a custom page with the following settings and code.

- Page URL: _____.tumblr.com/**following.json**
- Page Type: **Custom Layout**
- Show a link to this page: **unchecked**

**Custom HTML:**

```
{block:Following}[
{block:Followed}  {
    "name": "{FollowedName}",
    "title": "{FollowedTitle}",
    "url" : "{FollowedURL}",
    "portrait": {
      "16": "{FollowedPortraitURL-16}",
      "24": "{FollowedPortraitURL-24}",
      "30": "{FollowedPortraitURL-30}",
      "40": "{FollowedPortraitURL-40}",
      "48": "{FollowedPortraitURL-48}",
      "64": "{FollowedPortraitURL-64}",
      "96": "{FollowedPortraitURL-96}",
      "128": "{FollowedPortraitURL-128}"
    }
  }, {/block:Followed}
  {}
] {/block:Following}
```

So I just visit i.e. http://arvn.tumblr.com/following.json
But I'm still looking for other alternatives.

Comment: Wow, this is a great idea! Still feels really hacky, but it seems to work. The biggest downside is how public this data could (theoretically) become. And it doesn't address followers at all. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of is to use a scrape the content off of Tumblr.com using some sort of script that knew where to look for the names.

This is not an ideal option because if Tumblr changes their code then your system breaks but hopefully it is a bit better than not having it at all. If the API says it doesn't exist I don't think there is any way to do it otherwise.

You could email support@tumblr.com and request it. Who knows, maybe you will get your wish. They are really nice people.

Comment: I did email Tumblr support and they told me "We hope to add support for Followers and Following data to the API in the future but don't have a specific timeframe right now." And yes, scraping the site is an option. I just hoped there was a better one.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Wish I could come up with a better way.